# Что такое "компаратив"?

Tags: лексика, морфология

Не могли бы вы поведать мне, что такое "компаратив"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компаратив - сравнительная степень прилагательного и наречия (быстрее, тише, медленнее и т.п. )Явление, которое продолжает вызывать споры среди лингвистов о месте таких слов среди других частей речи.

Comment: >>>Явление, которое продолжает вызывать споры среди лингвистов о месте таких слов среди других частей речи.  
  
Что-то я не в теме. О чем споры?

Comment: Некоторые считают компаратив отдельной частью речи. Кажется, в "Грамматике" прочитала. А мне  не совсем понятно вот что: если наречие - неизменяемая часть речи, то что же такое сравнительная степень? Разве там слово не меняется? Причем  суффиксы ср. степени считаются ФОРМОобразующими.(Я понимаю, что говоря таким образом, имеют в виду, что наречие не склоняется и не спрягается).

Answer (score 1):

> А мне не совсем понятно вот что: если
> наречие - неизменяемая часть речи, то
> что же такое сравнительная степень?
> Разве там слово не меняется? Причем
> суффиксы ср. степени считаются
> ФОРМОобразующими.

Тут есть лазейка. Компаратив можно рассматривать как сравнительную степень имён прилагательных (причастий), а наречия, верно, неизменяемы ))) 
В пользу такого, несколько формалистского, подхода говорит  возможность образовать компаратив только от качественных производных наречий, в основном однокоренных соответствующим именам прилагательным; непроизводные вроде "очень", "здесь" или "едва", а также производные вроде "сгоряча", "навеселе", "дуриком", "назло", "наутро" и т.д компаратива, как известно, не образуют.
Вообще же язык - стихия живая, и важно помнить, что вносимые наукой о языке подразделения, определения и классификации никогда не могут быть абсолютно адекватными языковой действительности...

Comment: to behemotus
1. Лично для Вас - видимо, никуда.
2. Давно ли "терминологический" и "бессодержательный" - синонимы? Особенно в науках о языке...
3.Меняет или может поменять семантику всего высказывания изменение почти любой грамматической формы, в том числе лица глагола, рода прилагательного, падежа существительного...

Comment: >1. Лично для Вас - видимо, никуда.  
  
Спасибо. Я тут останусь. 

>2. Давно ли "терминологический" и "бессодержательный" - синонимы? Особенно в науках о языке...   
  
Всегда. Особенно в науках о языке...    
Ибо нигде более так не справедливо высказывание "хоть горшком назови..."

>3.Меняет или может поменять семантику всего высказывания изменение почти любой грамматической формы, в том числе лица глагола, рода прилагательного, падежа существительного...   
   
Нет. флексии, формообоазующие суффиксы на смысл не влиябт, а служат исключительно для синтаксической связи.

Answer (score 0):

Лазейка - куда? Или для чего?
Спор чисто терминологический, а потому - бессодержательный. Или я чего-то не понимаю, и отнесение наречий к изменяемым частям речи как-то скажется на том, что такое компаратив?

Что до сути, то я тем более не выжу проблемы. Под изменяющимися частями речи разумеют такие, которые допускают изменение, не вносящее нового смысла, т.е. исключительно в синтаксических целях (в русском, как это было сказано - склонение и спряжение). Сравнительная степень - это уже не синтаксис и не голая грамматика, а сравнении с обычной формой она меняет или может поменять семантику всего высказывания.